# I need help to write out put of the following code into A.txt in mirtoolbox1.5 file?

Tags: feature-extraction

I need help to write out put of the following code into A.txt file. Kindly tell me.....
I am currently working on feature extraction from audio using mirtoolbox..

> > miraudio('b1');
> > Chunk 1/2...
> > Computing miraudio related to b1...
> > Chunk 2/2...
> > Computing miraudio related to b1...
> > Computing mirsum related to b1...
> > Elapsed time is 3.128537 seconds.
> > mirrms(ans);
> > Computing mirrms related to b1...
> > rms=ans;
> > rms

The RMS energy related to file b1 is 0.28439

Answer (score 0):

> > r=mirrms('audiofile.mp3');
> >     Computing mirrms related to b1...
> >     test=get(r,'Data');
> >     test{1,1}{1,1}

ans =

```
0.2844
```

that is the right way.